# Update Sql db with a NULL value passed from Parameter

Tags: t-sql

I need to store a value with Null which is passed from a parameterized query using VB.net into SSEE 2008 R2.

The value maybe either 'Null' or a blank string "". How can I test for this and properly UPDATE the field in my Stored Procedure?

EDIT: Added declarations.

```
@ID int,    
@currTable varchar(150),
@prev_LangString nvarchar(max),
@brief_Descrip nvarchar(max)

BEGIN
 IF @brief_Descrip IS NULL OR @brief_Descrip = 'Null'
 SET @brief_Descrip = 'Null';
END

BEGIN
 SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET [date_Changed] = ''' +  convert(varchar(20), @submitDate1) + ''', [prev_LangString] = ''' + @prev_LangString + ''',  [brief_Descrip] = ''' + @brief_Descrip + '''
       WHERE (ID = ' + CAST(@ID as nvarchar(10)) + '); '

       EXECUTE(@sql);
END
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: And: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting @brief_Descript to a string.  This will also fix your injection vulnerability.

```
BEGIN
 IF @brief_Descrip = 'Null'
 SET @brief_Descrip = NULL;
END

UPDATE TABLE table_name
SET
  date_Changed = convert(varchar(20), @submitDate1),
  prev_LangString = @prev_LangString,
  brief_Descrip =  @brief_Descrip,
WHERE
  ID = CAST(@ID as nvarchar(10))
```

**EDIT**

The best way to fix this is to convert the string null to DBNull in vb.net, and use a parameterized query with an update statement.
You should not convert the date to a string.  Change the column type to a date time.

Comment: Table name is a variable. I have had problems getting code to execute when table name is a variable when trying to use it as you have written. I am always concerned about injection also, but in this instance the interface is not public, its limited to employees. "@brief_Descrip" is a string field, nvarchar to be exact. I'll edit and add the declarations. I'll check on the date field also. thanks,

Comment: @march11h, I know it is a variable, but it should not be.  Granted, it would not be hard to sanitize the table name, but you would still be using dynamic sql. No matter how much you trust your users, it is still a terrible idea to write code with a security vulnerability.  Whatever you are trying to accomplish, there is a better way to go about it.  I can't give you more specific advice without seeing the code that calls the SQL.

Comment: Thanks @mikerobi, actually the database names are built by code. No user ever has the ability to input that field data. I have up to about 30 potential DB tbl names based on foreign languages, when a user is created to translate for a given language, a table is built for that lang, ie. tblLangfrFR for French, tbl name is stored in DB table. When one of possibly say 5 translators login to translate Eng to Fr, I retieve the table name from db to update it based on translations made by translators, I then need to pass the table name to SP. Might Fr, or IT, or JP. I like your sol but its not workg

Comment: The BEGIN 
 IF brief_Descrip = 'Null' 
 SET brief_Descrip = NULL; 
END is not working. I am passing in Null as the value for brief_Descrip and the Update stmt will not fire. Any ideas? Had to remove at symbol on variables.

Comment: @marc11h, I don't understand why you couldn't store different languages in multiple tables, but do whatever works for you.  If that is what you want to do, my suggestion would be to sanitize the table name and use string substitution on an SQL template from within your application code. Convert brief_Descrip from "Null" to DBNull

Comment: Can you tell me if this is the correct syntax?  SET brief_Descrip = Convert(@brief_Descrip, dbNull);              I do store each language in its own table, but each table may not be created for a few months or years to come, and may be more than 30 languages, FYI.  thanks again.   "at symbols removed from brief_Descrip"

Comment: And how can I convert it in the If stmt?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a parameterized query. It would even make your problem go away. Like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000), @params NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @currTable + ' SET date_changed = @p0, prev_langstring = @p1, brief_descrip = @p2 WHERE id = @p3'
SET @params = '@p0 VARCHAR(20), @p1 VARCHAR(???), @p2 VARCHAR(???), @p3 NVARCHAR(10)'

DECLARE @sd VARCHAR(20), @sid NVARCHAR(10)
SET @sd = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @submiteDate1)
SET @sid = CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10))
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @p0 = @sd, @p1 = @prev_langstring, @p2 = @brief_descrip, @p3 = @sid
```

I don't know the datatype of `@prev_langstring` and of `@brief_descrip`, hence the `VARCHAR(???)` you see above; replace it by the real datatype.
You can read about `sp_executesql` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).